# Как предотвратить POST-запрос с уже имеющимися данными на сервере

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, axios

Я создаю сайт с авторизацией и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в данных не было дубликатов, например:

> На сервере уже зарегистрирован пользователь с *login: FirstUser*, и если какой-то другой человек пытается создать аккаунт с таким-же логином, то ему нужно выдать ошибку.

Я в принципе могу сделать перед отправкой POST-запроса, получить GET-запрос всех  пользователей, и найти сходство и если найду, то выдать ошибку, но я думаю есть какой-то простой вариант

Comment: Наоборот, следует рассчитывать, что в данных неизбежно могут оказаться дубликаты (или еще какие невалидные данные) и возвращать соотв. ошибку при обработке POST запроса.

Comment: А в чём сложность проверять дубликаты на сервере, и отправлять отказ в случае, если такой логин уже занят?